# Has the United States started a drone crop spraying program for farmers?

Tags: usa, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aerial-application, china

On *"NHK World"* (2018.06.01), a news segment showed Chinese farmers being taught to use drones to spray chemicals on their crops. The Chinese Government hopes to train all the farmers in an entire province.

Has the United States started any similar drone crop spraying program for farmers?

Is there any speculation on impact to future agriculture pilot jobs?

Comment: Well if we're going to keep jobs by keeping people using obsolete tools, how about tilling the fields the old fashioned way, bonus, also makes jobs for the mules!